# Does casting null to string cause boxing?

Tags: c#, boxing

Imagine code like this:

```
var str = (String)null;
```

Does it differs from:

```
String str;
```

Or:

```
String str = null;
```

Does the first code cause boxing of null value, or is it rather resolved at compiler time to string?

Comment: Why would any of this cause boxing? There are no value types involved.

Comment: I just understood that I messed boxing with conversions types :)

Comment: Well boxing doesn't get involved at all unless you're converting between a value type and a reference type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take your question and pick it apart.

Will the code in your question cause boxing?

No, it will not.

This is not because any of the 3 statements operate differently (there are differences though, more below), but boxing is not a concept that occurs when using strings.

Boxing occurs when you take a *value type* and wrap it up into an *object*. A `string` is a *reference type*, and thus there will never be boxing involved with it.

So boxing is out, what about the rest, are the three statements equal?

These two will do the same:

```
var str = (String)null;
String str = null;
```

The third one (second one in the order of your question though) is different in the sense that it only declares the `str` identifier to be of type `String`, it does not specifically initialize it to `null`.

**However**, if this is a field declaration of a class, this will be the same since all fields are initialized to defaults / zeroes when an object is constructed, and thus it will actually be initialized to `null` anyway.

If, on the other hand, this is a local variable, you now have an uninitialized variable. Judging from the fact that you write `var ...`, which is illegal in terms of fields, this is probably more correct for your question.

Comment: I chose this answer as it was really easy to understand :).
I just understood that I messed boxing with conversions types, but I found documentation so I'm good to go. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 9):

`String` is a reference type, so no, there's no boxing.

```
var str = (String)null;
String str = null;
```

These two are equivalent. In the first line, the compiler infers the type of `str` from the right hand side of the expression. In the second line, the cast from `null` to `string` is implicit.

```
String str;
```

The last one is equivalent to `String str = null` *if* it's a field declaration, which means `str` will be assigned its default value, which is null. If, however, `str` is a local variable, it'll have to be explicitly assigned before you can use it.

Answer (score 4):

MSDN says,

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object

`String` is not a value type and so there will be no boxing/unboxing.

Yes they are equal. Since string is a reference type even if you say `string str`; it will get default value which is `null`

Answer (score 3):

These two are equal:

```
var str = (String)null;
String str = null;
```

However, this one,

```
String str;
```

Depending on the context might or might not be equal to previous expressions. If it's a local variable, then it's not equal. You must explicitly initialise it. If it's a class variable, then it's initialised to null.

**Neither cause boxing.**